# OSB with Java Callout

Tags: java, deployment, jar, osb

I'm facing an issue. On testing a java code with external jar dependency separately, it is working. But when trying to deploy OSB code with java callout calling the same java code, it is throwing method does not exist.

Comment: If you have used any external jar in your java code please ensure that those jars must be exists on weblogic server where your OSB is hosted.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I include the external jar in weblogic server?

Comment: Please import your external jar in your osb project, where you have placed your java Callout jar

Comment: This issue was resolved by following the steps in the below blog:

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/generating-executable-jar-file

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to resolve this issue.

1. you can create a fat jar(it will contain all class files, Tools are available online or can use Eclipse or any ide to export the code.) for your Java code along with Dependencies and libraries.
2. You can deploy your dependencies as libraries/Application or copy Weblogic lib folder it depends on your dependency type. after deployment, you must restart the domain. Then u can deploy import your java callout Jar/Archive in OSB.